# all.different function in R, apply it in a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, unique, distinct, difference

I have a vector of numbers. For instance like this, with only a few unique values:

```
set.seed(2)
a = rpois(1000, 0.3)
head(a, 20)
#### [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 0
```

Now what I need is to find for each number, *if itself, the previous and the following element are all different*. I tried to find a function all.different or all distinct in R, unsuccessfully, so I made it:

```
all.diff = function(num) NROW(unique(num))==NROW(num)
```

Then I came up with a `for` loop like this:

```
ConsecutiveDifferent = function(vector) {
  output = numeric(NROW(vector)-2)
  for (i in 2:(NROW(vector)-1) ) {
    trio <- c(vector[i-1], vector[i], vector[i+1])
    if ( all.diff(trio) ) output[i]<-1
  }
  return(output)
}
res = ConsecutiveDifferent(a)
head(res, 20)
#### [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

It does the job but since my vector has a length of several hundred millions, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this than a loop.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

Thanks for getting me so many solutions! I coulnd't decide whose answer has to be accepted so I did a microbenckmark (length=50000) and the prize goes to Franck.. Also thanks for the extensive answer.
[image]

Comment: Not sure why you're using NROW. `length` is the usual thing for vectors.

Comment: you're right, that's a bad habbit... ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, are these much of an improvement over your original code (which I don't see in the benchmark)?

Comment: @Frank my code is in fact the last one "Marc" (sorry i used my first name)

Comment: Ah ok, got you mixed up with the answerer below of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**rle.** This is very particular to the case of trios:

```
w = with(rle(a), cumsum(lengths)[ 
  lengths == 1L & c(NA, values[-length(values)]) != c(values[-1], NA)
])

res2    = c(NA, logical(length(a)-2), NA)
res2[w] = TRUE

identical(res, res2) # TRUE
```

---

**combn.** I might do

```
a_shift    = list(c(NA, a[-length(a)]), a, c(a[-1], NA))
n_distinct = rowSums(combn(a_shift, 2, FUN = function(x) x[[1]] != x[[2]]))
res        = n_distinct == length(a_shift)
```

To examine whether it worked...

```
head(cbind.data.frame(a, res), 20)


   a   res
1  0    NA
2  0 FALSE
3  0 FALSE
4  0 FALSE
5  1 FALSE
6  1 FALSE
7  0 FALSE
8  1 FALSE
9  0 FALSE
10 0 FALSE
11 0 FALSE
12 0 FALSE
13 1 FALSE
14 0 FALSE
15 0 FALSE
16 1  TRUE
17 2  TRUE
18 0 FALSE
19 0 FALSE
20 0 FALSE
```

This can be extended to looking further ahead and behind by extending `a_shift`, which can be easily done with the `shift` function from data.table:

```
library(data.table)
n_back = 1
n_fwd  = 1
a_shift = setDT(list(a))[, c(
  shift(V1, n_back:0, type="lag"), 
  list(shift(V1, n_fwd, type="lead"))
)]
a_shift[, r := .I]

resDT = melt(a_shift, id = "r")[, .(res = 
  if (any(is.na(value))) NA else uniqueN(value) == n_fwd + n_back + 1L
), by=r][, a := a]

 identical(res, resDT$res) # TRUE
```

... which may look arcane, but that's more to do with my coding style than the package.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps do not use an iterator function (apply like function), and I think it is going to be faster

```
 da = diff(a)
 lda = c(0,da)
 rda = c(da,0)
 sda = lda + rda
 res = lda != 0 & rda != 0 & sda != 0
```

`res` contains `FALSE` in the first and last position, and it has the same length as vector `a`.

Comment: Huh, weird that the OP's test found this to be slower. I'm not sure what's slowing it down, but maybe the final step could be `res = (!!lda)*(!!rda)*(!!sda)` or something.

Comment: It remains slower even with 10 million-length vector. But indeed, the improvement suggested by @Franck decreases time by 30% and makes this algo N°1. Nice team work!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `duplicated` function

```
adjacent_dif <- function(i,l){
  as.numeric(!any(duplicated(c(l[i-1], l[i], l[i+1]))))
}

sapply(2:length(a)-1, adjacent_dif, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly as sin, but it works.

```
set.seed(2)
a <- rpois(1000, 0.3)

a_shifted <- embed(a,3)

indices <- 1 + which(apply(X = a_shifted,
                           FUN = function(num) {length(unique(num))==length(num)},
                           MARGIN = 1))
print(a[indices])
```

Comment: you can use `embed` for a_shifted

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `embed`, but it is clearly better for this purpose. Fixed.